# Rate of Convergence of complicated sequence with interactions

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization

I have been working on a problem where the sequence turns out to be so complex that i am unable to find its convergence rate with necessary and sufficient conditions on the parameters.After working through the math I got $$(a+cx_{t-1})x_t \leq cx_{t-1}^2 $$

Assume $a,c$ are variable (but not dependent on $t$) and $x_0$ is the initial point.
It would be great if anyone can help me finding its convergence rate and point me to a good reference.

Comment: Do you mean "assume $a,c$ are contant"? That is, they do not change with respect to $t$?

Comment: yup! with maybe conditions on them if necessary

Comment: The inequality makes it difficult to say anything, it would be better to have an equality and/or more detail on the constants.  For example, let $x_0$ and $a$ be any numbers that satisfy $x_0a \leq 0$.  Then $x_t=x_0$ for all $t$ satisfies your inequality.  Or, let $c\leq 0$ and $a\leq 0$ and $x_n$ be any sequence that satisfies $0 < x_0 < x_1 < \cdots$.

Comment: But i am dealing here with a stochastic optimization problem to be precise so i can only have inequality in the equation to comment on the convergence which otherwise leads to change of problem itself. I agree with your comments but it is of more interest to look at the sequence with decreasing trend to zero with increasing t. I actually oversimplified it for you here is the actual equation (if you really want to know)

Comment: \begin{align*}
(2\eta - \frac{2}{\mu} - 8L\eta^2  - \frac{8}{\mu}\zeta\bar{L}\sigma^2\eta^2 - \frac{16}{\mu}\zeta\bar{L}L\eta^2E[f(\tilde{x}_{s-1}) - f(x_*)])E[f(\tilde{x}_s) - f(x_*)]\\
 \leq  (8L\eta^2 + \frac{8}{\mu}\zeta\bar{L}\sigma^2\eta^2  + \frac{16}{\mu}\zeta\bar{L}L\eta^2E[f(\tilde{x}_{s-1}) - f(x_*)])E[f(\tilde{x}_{s-1}) - f(x_*)] \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Your (original) inequality is equivalent to $cx_{t-1}(x_t-x_{t-1}) \leq -ax_t$.  So if $c\geq 0$ and $a\leq 0$, then it is satisfied for any non-negative and non-increasing sequence $x_t$, including any sequence that decreases to $0$.

Comment: If you can assume that $x_t \geq 0$ for all $t$, and if $a>0$, then you can get a bit further.  For example, suppose $a > 0, c>0$.  Then $x_t \leq (c/a)x_{t-1}^2$ for all $t$.  If $x_0 \in [0, 1)$ then this converges to $0$ quite fast.

Comment: Does that mean it can have arbitrary convergence rate (if we consider any sequence with your suggested constraints) or is it going to something different completely

Comment: that looks good so it is quadratic convergence then let me put this in my context and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x_t \geq 0$ for all $t$, and that $c > 0$, $a >0$.  The inequality becomes:

$$ x_t \leq \frac{cx_{t-1}^2}{a+cx_{t-1}} \: \: \mbox{for all $t \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$}  \: \: \: (\mbox{Equation A})$$

Assume $x_0>0$ and define $\rho = \frac{1}{\frac{a}{cx_0} + 1}$. Note that $0< \rho < 1$.

Claim 1: We have $0 \leq x_t \leq \rho  x_{t-1}$ for all $t \in \{1, 2, 3,  \ldots\}$.

Proof: It holds for $t=1$ by directly considering equation (A).   Suppose it is true for $t$ (and in particular, $x_t \leq x_0$).  We prove for $t+1$. By equation (A) we get: 
\begin{align*}
x_{t+1} &\leq \frac{cx_{t}^2}{a+cx_{t}}\\
&= \frac{x_{t}}{\frac{a}{cx_{t}}+1}\\
&\leq \frac{x_{t}}{\frac{a}{cx_0} + 1}\\
&=\rho x_t
\end{align*}
$\Box$

Claim 1 proves that $x_t$ converges to 0 with a rate that is at least exponential.  The next claim shows it goes even faster than exponentially once it gets sufficiently close to $0$.

Claim 2:  For all $t$ we have $x_t \leq (c/a)x_{t-1}^2$.

Proof: By equation (A) we get: 
\begin{align} 
x_t &\leq \frac{cx_{t-1}^2}{a + cx_{t-1}} \\
&\leq \frac{cx_{t-1}^2}{a}
\end{align} 
$\Box$

Comment: just awesome! thanks

Comment: Would the following equation has the same quadratic convergence $$x_t \leq \left[\frac{b + cx_{t-1}}{a-b - cx_{t-1}}\right]x_{t-1}$$ when close to zero for some positive b,c,a. Or it seems like it has quadratic convergence when it is not close to zero.

Comment: It does not look like $x_t \leq (b+cx_{t-1})x_{t-1}/(a-b-cx_{t-1})$ has quadratic convergence to zero.  But if you assume $x_t\geq 0$ for all $t$,  assume $a,b,c$ positive and $0 < b/(a-b) < .9$, and define $x_{max}$ as the value such that $0 \leq (b+cx)/(a-b-cx) \leq 0.9$ whenever $0 \leq x \leq x_{max}$, then if $x_t \in [0, x_{max}]$  we have $0 \leq x_{t+1} \leq 0.9 x_t \leq x_{max}$. So we get exponential convergence to 0.

Comment: An example sequence that satisfies your recursion and that decays to zero exponentially is when $b/(a-b) = 0.5$, $(b+c\epsilon)/(a-b-c\epsilon) = 0.9$,  and $x_t = \epsilon (1/2)^t$ for $t \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.